# How to keep a JSON structure when I send it to Spark Streaming

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, streaming

I am receiving a JSON input that has several lines and attributes on Spark Streaming by using the command in Java:

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream <String> 
lines = ssc.socketTextStream 
(localhost, port)
```

I now want to filter the lines stream, so that it only has two specific attributes in each line, and dumps the rest.

The problem here is that I noticed that lines doesn't keep the JSON structure, that is, I can't just do

```
JavaDstream<String> line=lines[1];
line.print() ;
```

My question is, how can I make my JavaDStream keep the structure of a JSON object, and then print the lines I want?

I hope I was clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manuel,

So basically your asking how do to make sure that entire JSON payload is single record in RDD or what is record boundary when you send message on socket.

So basically the socketTextStream that your using reads the message on socket and if it finds a new line character it will use that as record boundary. The actual code for listening to socket, reading message and passing it to Spark is part of SocketReceiver.bytesToLines() method and if you look at the comment this is what it says

```
/**
 * This methods translates the data from an inputstream (say, from a socket)
 * to '\n' delimited strings and returns an iterator to access the strings.
*/
```

So make sure to take out \n character from the JSON message that your sending to spark as single record

Sunil

Comment: Dear Sunil,
Thank you for your answer. but it isn't exactly what I want. What I wanted was for example this:

I have a JSON file that I sent to Spark Streaming using socketTextStream, called 'lines'. If I want to print the whole 'lines' dstream, I just do lines.print, and it works.

If however I want to print a specific attribute value (for example the value of the first attribute in the first line, lines[1,1], I can't.
How can I do this?

Comment: Basicaly I want one line to correspond to one RDD from the stream.

Comment: If your interested in converting a JSON file to Stream you might want to use sparkStream concept of sparkStreamingContext.textFileStream(directoryToMonitor) . The way it works is you can monitor a particular HDFS directory for files whenver a new JSON file appears Spark will convert it into RDD for you. YOu can find sample of this at http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2016/01/monitoring-hdfs-directory-for-new-files.html

Comment: Thank you for your help Sunil, I think I know how to proceed from now on.